# How do I position my div right?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I can't seem to get my div in the right position. And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I hope someone can help me:

**HTML**

```
<div class="aspectwrapper">
<div class="content">
<div id="ontwerp">
<div class="inhoud1">
blablabla
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#inhoud1 {
position:fixed;
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Check out my edit. I've got it working for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.inhoud1 {
position:absolute;
left: 400px;
top: 100px;
}
```

`.inhoud1` instead of `#inhoud1` because it's a class and not an id. This is likely why it's been mysteriously not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `position: fixed` it will always float on a position, even if you scroll!

So, please try this:

#### First way

```
.inhoud1 {
  float: right; // first method
}
```

#### Second way

```
.inhoud1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; // no margin-right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

copy this

```
CSS

#ontwerp {
position : relative;
}
.inhoud1 {
position:absolute;
right: 0;

}
```